Why does this print on two pages (of which one is blank)?
I am trying to have HTML generate a PDF that fits exactly one page.
I would expect this to do the job:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    margin: 0mm; /* Adjust margins as needed */
}

body, html {
    margin:  0mm;
    padding: 0mm;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* 4 columns with equal width */

    grid-gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between grid items */

    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the grid container and add some margin */
    padding: 0px; /* Add padding inside the grid container */

    width: calc(841pt - 2px);
    height: calc(594pt - 2px);
}

.item {
    background-color: lightgrey;

    font-size: 18px; /* Example font size */
    text-align: center; /* Center align text */

    margin:  0px;
    padding: 0px;

    height: 100%;
}
/*
this is the bit that handles the margin inside the
grid container
*/
.item div {
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    height: 100%;

}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Aspernatur ut consequuntur voluptatem ipsam consectetur. Minima aut
dolorem delectus voluptatem corporis numquam. In occaecati quis
consectetur. Eum eligendi ab nulla beatae inventore et. Eveniet
perferendis mollitia consequatur.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Magnam cumque dolores qui tenetur consequuntur perferendis. Eum
temporibus quis eum voluptate quia id eaque totam. Veritatis eveniet et
occaecati fuga aut ut eveniet.
      </div>
</div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Facere cumque eum consequatur earum incidunt quia accusantium suscipit.
Eum placeat mollitia quasi quidem distinctio aut. Sunt porro aliquam
possimus necessitatibus odio culpa eum rerum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Amet eaque expedita repellendus quo enim nemo dolores consectetur.
Recusandae eos necessitatibus qui qui ipsam voluptatem ipsa quam. Qui
non ducimus laboriosam suscipit.
cumque sapiente et.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Maiores eligendi deserunt qui autem consequuntur ducimus. Quia dolores
dolores porro sed et et laboriosam autem. Vitae rem cupiditate in et
minima sit perferendis.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
    Magnam cumque dolores qui tenetur consequuntur perferendis. Eum
temporibus quis eum voluptate quia id eaque totam. Veritatis eveniet et
occaecati fuga aut ut eveniet.
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Facere cumque eum consequatur earum incidunt quia accusantium suscipit.
Eum placeat mollitia quasi quidem distinctio aut. Sunt porro aliquam
possimus necessitatibus odio culpa eum rerum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>
Amet eaque expedita repellendus quo enim nemo dolores consectetur.
Recusandae eos necessitatibus qui qui ipsam voluptatem ipsa quam. Qui
non ducimus laboriosam suscipit.
cumque sapiente et.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


but when I convert it to PDF like this:
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --headless=new --print-to-pdf-no-header --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf-no-header --print-to-pdf=empty.pdf empty.html 

I get two pages, of which one is blank.
Why, why, why?

Did you try to add * {box-sizing: border-box} to ensure that the padding are calculated in the widths of the elements?

Bingo! that works perfectly. Want to add that as an answer I'll gladly accept? and then I'll go back and study. This looks interesting

This question is similar to: CSS 100% height with padding/margin. I won't post a new answer, but thank you for letting me know it's working. :)

height: 100%; in .item div should be removed. It makes the div in .item taller than .item, out of range for this page.
.item div {
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    /* height: 100%; */
}

